# Connecting to RDS database from EC2 instance using bind9 CNAME alias

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, bind, rds

**Update:** it's working by now. Turns out I was missing a valid DNS forwarder inside the `named.conf.options` file.

I'm trying to get internal DNS up and running on a EC2 instance. The main goal is to be able to define CNAME aliases for other AWS services. For example: Instead of using the RDS endpoint, which might change over time, an alias `mysql.company.int` can be used instead.

I'm using `bind9` and here's my config files:

`/etc/bind/named.conf.local`

```
zone "company.int" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.company.int";
};
```

`/etc/bind/db.company.int`

```
;
$TTL    3600
@       IN      SOA     company.int. company.localhost. (
                   20120617         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@ IN  NS  company.int.
@ IN  A 127.0.0.1
@ IN  AAAA  ::1

; CNAME
mysql IN CNAME xxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com.
```

The `dig` command ensures me my alias is working as excepted:

```
$ dig mysql.company.int
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mysql.company.int.  3600    IN  CNAME   xxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com.
xxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com. 60 IN CNAME ec2-yyy-yy-yy-yyy.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
ec2-yyy-yy-yy-yyy.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 589575 IN A zzz.zz.zz.zzz
...
```

As far as I can understand a reverse zone isn't needed for a simple CNAME alias. However when I try to connect to MySQL using my newly created alias the operation is giving me a timeout.

```
$ mysql -uuser -ppassword -hmysql.company.int
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.company.int' (110)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advantage!

Comment: What is the output of `getent hosts mysql.company.int` and `telnet mysql.company.int mysql`?

Answer (score 1):

Is xxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com resolved to the IP address of the RDS endpoint on the computer you run the 'mysql' command on? We have a similar setup, but in our case 'dig' lists the actual IP address of the RDS endpoint in the answer section, i.e.:

```
$ dig mysql.company.int
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mysql.company.int.  3600    IN  CNAME   xxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com.
xxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
...
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't include the whole dig response. See the updated post above.